# Lambda Action Syntax in WCF call

Tags: wcf, web-services, authentication, mvvm-light

I have an Interface for a WCF service

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    void Authenticate(Action<bool, Exception> callback, string UserName,string Password);
}
```

I have an implementation

```
public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    public void Authenticate(Action<bool, Exception> callback, string Name, string Password)
    {
        MvcWebAuthenticate.AuthenticationServiceClient authService = new MvcWebAuthenticate.AuthenticationServiceClient();
        authService.CookieContainer = AuthCookie.CookieJar;
        authService.LoginCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Result == false)
            {
                callback(false, e.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                callback(true, null);
            }
        };
        authService.LoginAsync(Name, Password, "", true);
    }
}
```

From my view model i want to call service above and pass username and password, but I don’t understand how to write a lambda expression in order to pass parameters and get a "callback" Action back.

if i didnt have UserName and Password i could write this code:

```
_dataService.Authenticate(
(authenticated, error) =>
{
if (error != null)
{     }
});
```

But how to achieve same when i need to pass parameters?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the issue, you should be able to just do this:

```
    _dataService.Authenticate((authenticated, error) =>
    {
        if (error != null)
        {
        }
    }, userName, password);
```